# Setting Screen Resolution for Extended Display on Windows 8

Tags: resolution, windows-8-preview, extended-desktop

I'm using a Dell Inspiron laptop with Windows 8 Developers Preview.

I've connected a second screen (some Dell 22 inch one) and have been using it with 'Extend these displays' options in the Screen Resolution settings. It use to be all fine but yesterday I changed my VGA cable to the 2nd monitor and since then the resolution of the 2nd monitor is not setting properly.

Earlier, while auto detecting the monitor, the right resolution use to appear but now, as you can see from the attached image, none of the resolution in the drop down fits with the right proportion.

So how do I set the right screen resolution. (I think the right one is 1680 x 1050 which is not there in the list)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) every display device has there own native resolution which they run on smoothly such as a 17" lcd panel with screen dpi(ppi) of 96 dpi has 1024x768 pixel with aspect ratio of 4:3.

all the resolution your os is showing is of 4:3 aspect ratio and you need the resolution of 16:10 (i.e. 1680x1050) **this problem can be resolved by manually installing monitors driver** from manufactures website. you can find url for this in the manual.

after installing the complete model name should come in the list with proper list of supported resolution including native resolution.

NOTE: the driver for your monitor might come in few kbs but install it anyway it will force your os to change resolution mentioned in list.

2) change the orientation setting somewhere below your resolution setting to something else which has 16:10 aspect ratio supported this will change your resolution list too.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not listed, sometimes you can force the resolution.

Click the Advanced settings then click "List all modes". It should be listed.

YMMV.

Comment: I checked in the Advance Settings... still couldn't find it. I'm not sure why but if I change it to my old VGA cable, it works fine (1920X1080)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I got an ATI Mobility Radeon video card. I have changed the scalling options (set to 0% Overscan) in the AMD Catalyst Control Center/My Digital Flat-Panels.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today when I connected my laptop to a library monitor I've used several times before. The monitor obviously wasn't being detected properly and the wrong aspect ratios were being displayed. I tried taking my VGA lead out and plugging it in the opposite way round. That sorted it!  Apparently the direction of the lead matters.